# Как проверить некое условие в Object.keys(obj).map?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Есть Json с данными

```
 {
    "food": {
        "food1": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Каша",
            "qty": "3"
        } ,
        "food2": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Рис",
            "qty": "21"
        } 
    }
}
```

И логика которая перебирает данные и рендерит их

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from './food.json';


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const template = Object.keys(data.food).map(item => 
        <div>
        <div key={data.food[item].id}>{data.food[item].name} </div>
        <div>{data.food[item].qty} порций</div>
        </div>
        )
        return(
        <div className="hello" style={{color: 'red'}}>    
           {template}
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Как в ходе цикла можно проверить колличество порций и в зависимости от этого менять контент `<div>{data.food[item].qty} порций</div>` на нужный
1 порЦИЯ, например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто же:

```
<div>{data.food[item].qty} {1 === data.food[item].qty ? 'порция' : 'порций'}</div>
```

Comment: спасибо! только оператор === не верен, работает просто со сравнением ==

Comment: Да, либо привести количество к типу number:
1 === +data.food[item].qty
Для того чтобы понять во что преобразовывается этот код после сборки, советую этот сервис:
https://babeljs.io/en/repl